# Number of sub-intervals for an array?

Tags: combinatorics

What's the number of continuous subintervals for an array of size n?
For example for array [1,2,3,4,5] this set would be

```
[1,2,3,4,5] + 
[1 2, 2 3, 3 4, 4 5] + 
[1 2 3, 2 3 4, 3 4 5] + 
[1 2 3 4, 2 3 4 5] + 
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

So the total number of subintervals for array of 5 elements is 15, for array of 4 elements it is 10. I don't see any particular pattern here...
Any ideas how to express this number of a function of n?

Comment: How do you define "continuous subinterval"?

Comment: It's just $$\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}2$$

Comment: @DonThousand can you elaborate how this summation relates to the problem?

Comment: @YohanRoth Fix $i$ in my answer, and vary $j$. Say, when $i=1, j$ varies from $1\to n$, giving $n$ contiguous subintervals. When $i=2,j$ varies from $2\to n$ giving $n-1$ contiguous subintervals. Finally, when $i=n,j$ can only be $n$, giving the contiguous subinterval $[n]$. The total is $1+2+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$

Comment: @YohanRoth All that matters is the starting point of the subinterval, and how long it is. Notice that there are 5 subintervals of length 1, 4 of length 2, 3 of length 3, etc etc. So it is simply a summation from 1 to n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $i,j$ be indices marking the start and end of the sub-interval respectively. We can select $i,j\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $i\ne j$ in $\binom n2$ ways, and assign $i$ as the smaller index and $j$ as the larger index of the selected indices. We can select $i,j$ such that $i=j$ in $n$ ways. The total is $\displaystyle\binom n2+n=\frac{n(n-1)}2+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$